# Save with specified name from the specified cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hello so I used the below coding to try to "save as" the active worksheet to the current same folder, however the problem I am facing is that the file name does not appear as E6 however it is just a blank.

Also, is there a faster way to actually just omit the save as dialog and just save as a new workbook in the same folder as the macro? With the same file type as xls. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim varResult As Variant
Dim dirPath, fileName As String


dirPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
fileName = ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Value 'ActiveSheet.Name


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
                 "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Save As", _
                InitialFileName:=dirPath & "\" & fileName)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=varResult

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: *just save as a new workbook in the same folder as the macro?* `ThisWorkbook.Path` should be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Another issue regarding the empty file name is still an issue nonetheless haha

Comment: Add `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path` and see what the result is in the Immediate Window :-)

Comment: I think you meant E6 right, hmm E6 will be taking agoto.2.2020, cause I am dealing with changing values every now and then and that cell is the constant.

Comment: Try, please to insert this line after the dialog: `Debug.Print varResult`. What does it return?

Comment: Both does not return anything different, still facing with the same issue tho ;/ I am a new learner so pardon me.

Comment: No different, no different, but what it returns, please?

Comment: I am not sure what does that mean, am i adding the code the wrong way? Please advise.  I copied it and added at the end of the script before End Sub and ran the macro.

Comment: I asked you about `varResult` variable displayed in `Debug.Print`. What value does it contain?

Comment: HowardFoo, to see the results of ```Debug.Print```, you should open the Immediate window in the VBA editor (ctrl+G.)  That is where ```Debug.Print``` outputs when the code runs.

Answer (score 1):

To directly save without using the dialog, try the next code, please:

```
Sub testSaveAs()
   Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'Use here your workbook
    wb.SaveAs fileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("E6").value & ".xls"
 End Sub
```